# Copying text from RichTextBox to WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, richtextbox

I am trying to copy text from a RichTextBox and paste it into a WebBrowser.

I use this code:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate("about:blank");

richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.Copy();

wb.Document.ExecCommand("Paste", false, null);
```

`wb.Document` always shows an empty document. `DocumentText` gives `<HTML> </HTML>\0` and `Document.Body` is `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The content of a RichTextBox is not HTML, so an incompatible clipboard format may be part of the issue.  If you are happy with the text only, try assigning the plain text to the clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetText(RichTextBox1.Text);
```

If you want formatted text, you will need to convert the RTF to HTML.  This article may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter

Answer (score 0):

Because your page html is null,try this example

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body></body></html>";
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText = richTextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to paste formatted text (bold, colored, ...). This only takes the text from the richtextbox.